# Pandas Numpy add a column

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array with that shape (n, ) that is an array of tuples that have multiple elements. Is there a way for me to quickly add a column to one of the tuples & it would still have the same shape (n,)?

Comment: Something like `array_of_tuples[i] = array_of_tuples[i] + (new_elem,)` should work, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Since there was no answer to this questions, I wrote a snippet which might be helpful. You can use `np.zeros` or `np.hstack` to add new column to the array.

```
import numpy as np

def main():
    my_tuples = np.array(((1,-2,3),(4,5,6))) 
    element = (7,8) #suppose you want to add this to my_tuples column

    #Solution 1
    print('shape before adding column', my_tuples.shape)
    new_tuples = np.zeros((my_tuples.shape[0],my_tuples.shape[1]+1));
    new_tuples[:,:-1] = my_tuples
    new_tuples[:,-1] = element
    print('column to be added ', element)
    print('shape after adding column using np.zeros', new_tuples.shape)
    print(new_tuples)

    #Solution 2
    new_tuples = np.hstack((my_tuples,np.zeros((my_tuples.shape[0],1))))
    new_tuples[:,-1] = element
    print('shape after adding column using np.hstack', new_tuples.shape)
    print(new_tuples)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Output:**

```
shape before adding column (2, 3)
column to be added  (7, 8)
shape after adding column using np.zeros (2, 4)
[[ 1. -2.  3.  7.]
 [ 4.  5.  6.  8.]]
shape after adding column using np.hstack (2, 4)
[[ 1. -2.  3.  7.]
 [ 4.  5.  6.  8.]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution, it dealth with adding a column to a structure array:

```
 from numpy.lib import recfunctions
 a = recfunctions.append_fields(old_data,'new_column', 
                                new_array,dtypes=np.float64,
                                usemask=False)
```